# Multiple JSESSIONID IN REQUEST HEADERS

Tags: java, cookies, websphere, setcookie, jsessionid

My fiddler trace looks like this:

```
Cookie / Login
C.LWSN=BLNCUJBMUyCAiyVztlU7fREOpDjFC4!2FUUmPJ1UTPUhWyQUl7gVFdMAAAAVbfn6pI
JSESSIONID=0000Fbsp0QmvTif-1v6OFxIEz7y; 
JSESSIONID=0000s2dD67nvl5G5pScW2cjYk0j:-1; 
KBJEILKHOJUWIOR2=MXQPuA6gDQMsi8ODwICE5Z9mKX7lShmIt5k0p6cbJ6I=;
```

Is it normal for my fiddler trace to contain two JSESSIONID?
Anyone knows what is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple JSESSIONID entries in the HTTP header is not unusual. Sometimes it is when the user has failed over from one cluster member to another. Sometimes it could be the previous JSESSIONID expired and the user picked up a new one (very code dependent so would need more detail). Behavior is version dependent and those cookie values look like they come from an older version of WAS. There is more detail if you google [websphere multiple jsessionid cookies](https://www.google.com/search?q=websphere%20multiple%20jsessionid%20cookies&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Comment: I tried applying the fix from this. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI31734 
It looks like it fix our problem.